# closedxml add image vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, closedxml

i am doing a webform in ASP.NET and currently working with ClosedXML,is there a way to insert an image inside a worksheet in a position?, i have this code

```
Dim wb As New XLWorkbook()
Dim ws As IXLWorksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("NAME")
Dim httpResponse = Response
httpResponse.Clear()
httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

'INSERT IMAGE HERE'
ws.insertimage("imagepath")'???

Dim namedoc As String = "namedoc"
httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""" + namedoc+ ".xlsx""")
Using tmpMemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    wb.SaveAs(tmpMemoryStream)
    tmpMemoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream)
    tmpMemoryStream.Close()
End Using
httpResponse.End()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** ClosedXML now supports images, see [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/How-can-I-insert-an-image).

---

**Original answer:**

> **How can I insert an image?**
>
> You can't. Although you can open an Excel that already has an image
>   and save it preserving the image, you can't insert a new image with
>   ClosedXML.

[from the official FAQ](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20can%20I%20insert%20an%20image%3F&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: thanks, that is good to know, there are a few ways but really complicated, in the end i used a file in blank with the image

Answer (score 0):

As Raidri says, I don't think you can.

But I got it working using Open XML using this, although it's not exactly straightforward:
http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/30/how-to-insert-an-image-in-excel-open-xml/